# how to import correctly the commons.apache.math libraries for my own project

Tags: java, eclipse, import, jar, apache-commons

I want to use the commons.apache.maths classes for my own project but I don't know how to correctly import them into eclipse. I have visited the download page for the package mentioned above http://commons.apache.org/math/download_math.cgi   but I don't know if the jar file which i want to import is on the binaries zip files or the source zip files. I tried the binaries ones first and when I do the import i just get a list of empty packages. Could somebody who knows how to do a correct import please show me how to do it?

What i am doing at the moment i am downloading the zip file from the link above, extracting it and than right-click my project->properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add External Jars. My issue is i don't know which jars to add.

Thanks in advance.
Arlind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to import this way.

```
import org.apache.commons.math
```

You can add the zip file in your build path or extract the jar files from the zip and add it to the build path. For example to add 2.1 of apache math you need this zip file **commons-math-2.1.zip** or extract **commons-math-2.1.jar** from the zip file and add it to your eclipse build path.

Another trick is - if you have the jar files or zip file added in your build path in eclipse then do **ctrl+shift+o** and eclipse will automatically import the packages for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask how do I find the build path? Is the build path where the java files are stored so for my computer this would be My Computer\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib. Thanks again.

Comment: If you are building your code via eclipse then right click on the project->properties->Java Build Path.

Comment: Outside of eclipse you will need to add -classpath to javac or it can be located from the CLASSPATH environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

There is `commons-math-2.1.jar` in the zip - add this to your project

Comment: thanks for reply. I know it may sound crazy but I already tried that and it didn't work. When i tried now it works.

Answer (score 0):

download the jar file, extract it locally. Open eclipse, project-property-java build path-libraries-add library, where you add the extracted folder there. then you can use the import org.apache.commons.math3.