# Check multiple null values in if statement using OR and store errors in an array

Tags: java

When user submit the form I want to check multiple text fields in a form and check whether it is null or not and it must show which input field is blank

```
String A = request.getparameter("a");
String B = request.getparameter("b");
String C = request.getparameter("c");
```

```
if(A==null || B==null || C==null)
{

//Here I want to store the corresponding errors in an arrayfield and it should display which field is empty.

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the implementation to this thne

```
if(A==null){
//A is null, add message
}
else if(B==null){
//error message against B
}
else if(C==null){
//error message against C
}
```

Use Apache Commons `StringUtils.isEmpty(str)`, which checks for empty strings and handles null gracefully.

so it would be something like

```
if(StringUtils.isEmpty(A)){ 

}
```

Comment: StringUtils.isEmpty(A) not working. Error showing method isEmpty(String) is undefined for the type StringUtils

Comment: have you imported `Apache Commons`?

Comment: No. How to import that? I am using maven. which import statement I need to put .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839754/how-to-import-correctly-the-commons-apache-math-libraries-for-my-own-project?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

// inside onCreate method do this

```
   //make this variable globle

   ArrayList<MyVariableNameValue> nullStringList=new ArrayList<>();
    for (MyVariableNameValue nullString: checkNull()) {
        Log.d("nullsize", "onCreate: "+nullString.getName());
    }
    //up to here
```

//create getter method class to store the variable name and value in mainactivity or outside it

```
 public class MyVariableNameValue{
    String name,value;
    public MyVariableNameValue(String name,String value){
        this.name=name;
        this.value=value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

//create a method to return null variable values and name in maiactivity

```
 public ArrayList<MyVariableNameValue> checkNull(){
    nullStringList.clear();
  String A = request.getparameter("a");
  String B = request.getparameter("b");
  String C = request.getparameter("c");
    ArrayList<MyVariableNameValue> checkString = new ArrayList<>();
    checkString.add(new MyVariableNameValue("A",A));
    checkString.add(new MyVariableNameValue("B",B));
    checkString.add(new MyVariableNameValue("C",C));
    for (MyVariableNameValue myString: checkString) {
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(myString.getValue())){
            nullStringList.add((myString));
        }

    }
    return nullStringList;
}
```